# Why is my Select Case not working

Tags: vb.net, select, case

Okay my question goes as follows; I think i coded everything right execpt for the part where i do my select case, I want the first 3 Flavours to only cost 55 cents but when I do my code it always makes the scoops 65 cents no matter what icecream type i select and i dont know how to make it change, i thought i had it right but it isnt working

```
Public Class frmJoeyIceCreamParlour
    Const MIN_SCOOPS = 1
    Const MAX_SCOOPS = 9
    Const BASIC_FLAVOUR = 0.55
    Const PREMIUM_FLAVOUR = 0.65
    Const TOPPING = 0.6
    Const DEEZ_NUTS = 0.5
    Const WHIPPED_CREAM = 0.65
    Public scoopEntry As Single
    Public scoopType As Double
    Public runningTotal As Double

    Private Sub frmJoeyIceCreamParlour_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lstFlavours.Items.Add("Vanilla")
        lstFlavours.Items.Add("Chocolate")
        lstFlavours.Items.Add("Strawberry")
        lstFlavours.Items.Add("Mango")
        lstFlavours.Items.Add("Bananna")
        lstFlavours.Items.Add("Grape")
        lstFlavours.Items.Add("Mint Chocolate Chip")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        If txtScoops.Text = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value in the scoops category.")
            txtScoops.Focus()

        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(txtScoops.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Entry must be numeric! Please try again.")
            txtScoops.Focus()

        ElseIf txtScoops.Text < MIN_SCOOPS Or txtScoops.Text > MAX_SCOOPS Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number between 1 and 9 scoops.")
            txtScoops.Focus()

        ElseIf lstFlavours.SelectedItem = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a flavour.")

        ElseIf rdoNoTopping.Checked = False And rdoOneTopping.Checked = False And rdoTwoTopping.Checked = False And rdoThreeTopping.Checked = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select the amount of toppings you would like.")

        Else
            Dim number As Integer = 7
            Select Case number

                Case 1 To 3
                    scoopType = BASIC_FLAVOUR
                Case 4 To 7
                    scoopType = PREMIUM_FLAVOUR

                    runningTotal = scoopType * Double.Parse(txtScoops.Text)
            End Select

            If rdoOneTopping.Checked = True Then
                runningTotal = runningTotal + TOPPING

            ElseIf rdoTwoTopping.Checked = True Then
                runningTotal = runningTotal + (TOPPING * 2)

            ElseIf rdoThreeTopping.Checked = True Then
                runningTotal = runningTotal + (TOPPING * 3)

            End If

            If chkWhippedCream.Checked = True Then
                runningTotal = runningTotal + WHIPPED_CREAM

             End If

            If chkNuts.Checked = True Then
                runningTotal = runningTotal + DEEZ_NUTS

            End If
            lblOutputTotal.Text = (FormatCurrency(runningTotal))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: try to use a compact, minimal code snippet that causes the problem. If the problem is in the select case, we don't need the hole method code.

Comment: ...then when you get an answer as you have, show your thanks by clicking the checkmark next to one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have it hard coded to use 7 via the line just above your `Select case number` statement: `Dim number As Integer = 7`.  You should instead be looking up the selected index by doing something like `Dim number As Integer = lstFlavours.SelectedIndex`

```
Dim number As Integer = lstFlavours.SelectedIndex
Select Case number

    Case 1 To 3
        scoopType = BASIC_FLAVOUR
    Case 4 To 7
        scoopType = PREMIUM_FLAVOUR
End Select

runningTotal = scoopType * Double.Parse(txtScoops.Text)
```

Comment: Okay i did what you asked, and now the first 3 show up as $0.00 and the others go as $0.65, do you have a solution for that ? @travis

Comment: Yea, move the `runningTotal = scoopType * Double.Parse(txtScoops.Text)` piece out of the select statement.  As it is currently written, only the 4 to 7 case hits that code.  I'll update my answer with a full example with both changes, one moment.